# Using Charles Debugging Proxy With Virtual Hosts on a Virtual Machine

Tags: debugging, http, proxy, virtualhost, charles-proxy

I have a Virtual Machine running on my Mac which I mount. This VM is running multiple virtual hosts.

When I load Charles and navigate to sites that sit on the VM, the response is incredibly slow. I've checked that there is no throttling turned on within Charles.

I'm wondering if anyone can think of why this might be occurring?

Comment: I'm also seeing this and I've only just determined that it only happens when navigating to sites on a VM. Did you find a solution?